# Android location from wifi only

Tags: android, gps, location, android-wifi

I've a custom HW running Android 4.4.4. It has a wifi connection but no GPS or cellular modules. I need to determine the location based on wifi only, but it seems Android can't. Visiting google.com in the browser also shows 'unknown' location. The wifi works ok though - browsing internet etc.

Here's my sample class to determine the location:

```
public class LocationServices {
    Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = LocationServices.class.getSimpleName();

    LocationServices(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Check if we can get our location */
    public void checkLocation(){
        // Get the location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String locationProviderWifi = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        String locationProviderGPS = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        LocationListener locationListenerNetwork;
        LocationListener locationListenerGPS;
        boolean gps_enabled=false;
        boolean network_enabled=false;

        //check wifi
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
             Log.d(TAG,"Wifi connected");
        }

        //check gps and wifi availability
        try{
            gps_enabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }catch(Exception ex){}

        try{
            network_enabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }catch(Exception ex){}

        if(!gps_enabled){
            Log.d(TAG,"GPS: Missing");
        }
        if(!network_enabled){
            Log.d(TAG,"Network: Missing");
        }

        /* Location change listeners */
        try{
            // Define a listener that responds to gps location updates
            locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"GPS: Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 1");}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 2");}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 3");}
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProviderGPS, 0, 0, locationListenerGPS);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Location Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try{
            // Define a listener that responds to wifi location updates
            locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"NW: Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 1");}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 2");}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 3");}
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProviderWifi, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Location Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And logcat output:

```
02-02 18:09:27.009: D/LocationServices(3972): Wifi connected
02-02 18:09:27.009: D/LocationServices(3972): GPS: Missing
02-02 18:09:27.009: D/LocationServices(3972): Network: Missing
02-02 18:09:27.016: E/LocationServices(3972): Location Exception: provider doesn't exist: gps
02-02 18:09:27.016: E/LocationServices(3972): Location Exception: provider doesn't exist: network
```

Permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Is there anyway to determine location in this configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are welcome to try to find some Web service that will provide geo-location based on public IP address lookup. The accuracy will range from "correct town" to "correct planet", depending upon networking configuration (e.g., VPN), ISP, etc.

Comment: So, is it not possible to get location using the LocationManager in Android if you only have wifi?

Comment: @rockford98: On your hardware, your manufacturer does not support the standard location sources, per your LogCat output. You are welcome to contact the manufacturer and ask them what to do. If you are unwilling or unable to talk to your manufacturer, your options are limited to using browser-style IP address lookup techniques or doing without location data outright.

Comment: understood. I just wanted to understand in general, that if at all it's possible to get location on Android devices from wifi only. I guess not. Looks like geolocation is my only resort. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using Google Play Services for obtaining location https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup ? If it's not working maybe you could get it from WebView using JavaScript interface ?